# Use of Indirect Cell References in Excel 2007 Custom Data Validation Rules

Tags: excel, validation

I'm having difficulty getting an INDIRECT reference to a cell that contains a dynamic maximum for data validation to work in Excel 2007. Here's what I'm using:

**Setting**: Custom w/ Allow Blanks Checked

**Data**: Is not selectable and contains the value "Between"

**Formula**: <=INDIRECT("R"&CELL("row")&"C"&CELL("col")+3,0)

The value entered must be less than or equal to the value contained 3 columns over.

Any suggestions very much appreciated. Thank you ...... Rick

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use a conditionnal formatting : INDIRECT is quite weird when going "live" whereas conditionnal formatting are easy to apply.

When setting such a formatting, keep in mind that the formula, just remove the "$".

I.e :

```
A1 : 3
A2 : 29
A3 : 16
A4 : (to be set up)

Select A4 :
Format -> conditionnal formatting
Value must be less or equal than =A1
```

be aware that when clicking A1, it will write $A$1, that is not wanted.
Then make the format "RED" with a pink background, and no mistake will be made.

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss the first half of the formula (referencing the current cell)?

```
=INDIRECT("R"&CELL("row")&"C"&CELL("col"),0)<=INDIRECT("R"&CELL("row")&"C"&CELL("col")+3,0)
```